# Density of mixture copula

Tags: copula

I understand the idea of copula and its benefits. One main advantage of the copula is it allows to model the margins distributions separately from the dependence structures. The density of bivariate joint distribution function using copula can be given as follows:

$f = c(F_1 (x_1), F_2(x_2)) \cdot f_1 \cdot f_2$

My question is how could I write the bivariate mixture density with the copula.

I was thinking about this:

$f = \sum_{i=1}^{2} \pi_i \cdot c_i$

However, how could I express the mixture margins (as shown in the first equation $f_1 \cdot f_2$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as before - one merely replaces a "simple" copula $c$ by a convex combination of copulas which is yet another copula: 
$$ f(x_1, x_2)=\big[\sum_{i=1}^{n} \pi_i c_i \big(F_1(x_1), F_2(x_2)\big)\big] \cdot f_1(x_1) \cdot f_2(x_2) $$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i = 1$ and $ \pi_i \geq 0,\ i=1, \dots n$.

The same can be done for the marginal densities and CDFs, one only needs to make sure that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are densities (and $F_1$ and $F_2$ their respective CDFs), no matter how they are defined (most likely using a different number $n$ and different weights $\pi_i$). Note, that this works nicely in the continuous case, but has many pitfalls in the discrete world - as almost always for copulas.

Comment: Could you please let me know why it is pifalls in the discrete world? Is that because copula is not unique in this case.